# getting "no video with supported format and mime type found" in php but no in html

Tags: php, html

I used video tag in an HTML file and it works fine.

```
          <div class="modal-body">
            <video id="cartoonVideo" width="560" height="315"   frameborder="0" allowfullscreen controls>
            <source src="<?baseUrl() ?>/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">

        </video>
```

when changing the format of the file to PHP on wamp server I get this error.

```
no video with supported format and mime type found
```

in the PHP file, I get the path from `$ _SERVER` with `baseUrl()` method, checked it and it's valid.
I'm using apache and enabled mp4 mime type by adding this line to `mime.types` file

```
video/mp4                   mp4 mp4v mpg4
```

in the console, I saw this warning:

> HTTP “Content-Type” of “text/html” is not supported. Load of media
>   resource "video url"

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're missing the opening PHP tag, plus you have an extra quote. Try changing this:

```
<source src="baseUrl() ?>/videos/video.mp4"" type="video/mp4">
```

To this:

```
<source src="<?php baseUrl(); ?>/videos/video.mp4" type="video/mp4">
```

Then save the file with a `.php` extension.

I'm surprised that this is working when the file is saved with an `.html` extension, because `baseUrl() ?>/videos/video.mp4"` is not a valid file path.

Comment: no, it missed when I typed the question, I've mentioned checking the path and it's valid

Comment: and HTML file not exactly like this. baseUrl returns a path that I had in HTML file

Comment: Are you sure the video is encoded correctly? Maybe try a different MP4 video and see if that works.

Comment: yes, I'm sure. I have 3 videos in that directory same format. downloaded from youtube